# ¿Se puede acortar este código mediante un bucle for?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy nuevo aquí. Mi duda es si hay alguna forma de resumir este código mediante un bucle `for`, ya que en Adobe Flash se me resultaba muy fácil de hacer:

```
if (curse == 9) {
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module901), R.mipmap.module901));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module902), R.mipmap.module902));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module903), R.mipmap.module903));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module904), R.mipmap.module904));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module905), R.mipmap.module905));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module906), R.mipmap.module906));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module907), R.mipmap.module907));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module908), R.mipmap.module908));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module909), R.mipmap.module909));
    list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string.Module910), R.mipmap.module910));
}
```

Mi idea era hacer algo así, pero no funciona:

```
    for (int i = 900; i < 910; i++){
        list.add(new Modules(getString(R.string["Module"+i]), R.mipmap["module"+i]));
    }
```

[image: Con 10000 líneas de código funciona]
[image: Con el bucle for queda así :(]

Necesito terminar una app con este código para antes del 15 de marzo
Espero haber sido claro y agradezco sus respuestas :)

Comment: Para lo que quieres hacer necesitas usar `Reflection` . Puedes ver la [documentación de Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) de Java para ver sus posibilidades. Si aportas más código sobre la clase a la que pertenece `R` podría darte un fragmento que haga lo que quieres, pero necesito ver el acceso y tipo de las variables `mipmap` y `module*`.

Comment: Hola! Lo que estoy implementando es un spinner, algo muy parecido a esto: [enlace] (https://danielme.com/2013/04/25/diseno-android-spinner)

Answer (score 3):

**No se trata únicamente de guardar como String todo lo que se tiene dentro de Modules( ) ya que vas a evaluar en realidad recursos del proyecto**:

```
list.add(new Modules( ... ));
```

Considero que tendrías que crear 2 arrays de enteros ya que lo que se guardará son ids de recursos y usarlos para instanciar la clase Modules y esta sea agregada al List:

```
for (int i = 900; i < 910; i++){
        list.add(new Modules(getString(arrayStringsModule[i]), arrayMipmapModule[i]));
}
```

- Importante, la clase `Modules`, debe recibir valores tipo Int : `Modules(int , int)`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);

    return getString(resId);
}

private String getMimapResourceByName(String aString) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "mimap", packageName);

    return getString(resId);
}
```

Y ahora ya haces el bucle:

```
for (int i = 900; i < 910; i++) {
    list.add(new Modules(getStringResourceByName("Module" + i), getMimapResourceByName("module" + i)));
}
```

Comment: ¿Quizás `getIdentifier(aString, "mipmap", packageName)`?

Answer (score -1):

**A.** El bucle debe ser evaluado usando `i < 911` para que se ejecute hasta que `i=910`.

**B.** Puesto que `i`en cada ocurrencia es un `Integer` hay que convertirlo a `String` (aquí uso `valueOf`, pero puedes usar otro método).
En la cadena `sGet` juntamos todo lo que queremos pasar al constructor de la clase `Modules`.

```
for (int i = 900; i < 911; i++){
    String sIterator=String.valueOf(i);
    String sGet="getString(R.string.Module" + sIterator + "),
                 R.mipmap.module" + sIterator;
    list.add(new Modules(sGet));
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu ayuda! El código que has sugerido está bien, pero el constructor Modules recibe dos parámetros (String, int). El problema está en "int". Coloco aquí el código que me ha quedado:  `  for (int i = 900; i < 911; i++){
                String iterator = valueOf(i);
                String NameRoute = "getString(R.string.Module"+iterator;
                int ImageRoute = "R.mipmap.module"+iterator;
                list.add(new Modules(NameRoute,ImageRoute));
            } `

Comment: ¡Ah! en la pregunta no se especificaba qué tipo de datos debía recibir el constructor... ¿Se resolvió con el código de tu comentario o lo que me quieres decir es que el constructor debe recibir dos datos del tipo `String`?

Comment: El constructor debe recibir un `String` y un `int`. Otro problema que sucedió fue que en el spinner que estoy haciendo todos los elementos quedaron como `getString(R.string.Module900)`; es decir no reemplaza el valor que busco

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor, estoy implementando el código de esta página: https://danielme.com/2013/04/25/diseno-android-spinner/

Comment: ¿O sea que esto `R.mipmap.module901` devuelve un valor del tipo `Integer`y tu clase  es así: `Modules(String, Integer)`? Imagino que en el 2º parámetro de la clase intentas pasar el nombre de una imagen o algo así... ¿por qué entonces representa un entero?

Comment: En la página donde busqué el código usa el Integer para los íconos de un spinner. Todos los `R.mipmap.module` son imágenes png. La única diferencia con el original es que yo uso `mipmap` en lugar de `drawable`

Comment: @cs10SergioCarp Ya, pero para obtener de esa manera tu imagen tienes que usar `getResources` más o menos así: `int panelId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(drawerSelection,"id",getActivity().getPackageName());` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)  Pero me pregunto si no sería mejor leer tus imágenes desde tu XML, teniéndolas ya en un array...

Comment: Sí, puede ser. Pero el problema de los `String` sigue persistiendo. Me gustaría subir una captura aquí, pero no sé si es posible. Discúlpame pero soy un novato en estos foros.

Comment: Ahí acabo de añadir las capturas. La 1° es como se ve mi app con 10.000 líneas de código. La 2° es con el bucle for

Comment: @cs10SergioCarp Esto está en inglés, pero creo que es lo que necesitas: http://www.intransitione.com/blog/advanced-listview-populating-a-list-with-images-and-text/ Construir un array en un XML que contenga las imágenes de la izquierda y el texto de la derecha y leerlo desde Java.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano! Ese código está muy bueno. Es una lástima que no exista en Android Studio algo tan simple que te simplifique la vida así, por ejemplo: `String var = "example"; Toast.makeText(this,R.string[var],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score -1):

Para estos casos, Reflection es tu amigo, aunque debes tener mucho cuidado con ello como ponen en la [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) ya que estás usando accesos delicados si no sabes lo que haces. Si quieres evitarlo, lo más fácil es hacer lo que dice @Jorgesys en su respuesta.

Para tu caso esto debería funcionar:

```
for (int i = 901; i <= 910; i++){
    list.add(new Modules(
        getString(R.string.getClass().getField("Module"+i).get(R.string),
        R.mipmap.getClass().getField("module"+i).getInt(R.mipmap)))
    );
}
```

Por otro lado deberías editar tu pregunta para añadir todo lo que has ido aclarando en los comentarios de la respuesta de @A.Cedano y que son más necesarios para ayudarte con tu problema que las imágenes que has subido. Así tu pregunta será más útil para el resto de la comunidad que puede no entenderla si no lee todos los comentarios del resto de publicaciones o si se borrase la citada respuesta.